# How can a setupfile being considered as safe while exporting through a batch process?

Tags: org-mode

In my `org-mode`-file I have a source cell which contains the various formats I want to export this file to.

```
#+title: How to export this document?
#+author: me
#+SETUPFILE: https://fniessen.github.io/org-html-themes/org/theme-readtheorg.setup

* Export feature
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports code :results none :var filename=(buffer-name)
emacs -Q "$filename" --batch -f org-html-export-to-html --kill
emacs -Q "$filename" --batch -f org-ascii-export-to-ascii --kill
emacs -Q "$filename" --batch -f org-latex-export-to-pdf --kill
#+END_SRC
```

When I execute the cell I get the error:
`The remote resource "https://fniessen.github.io/org-html-themes/org/theme-readtheorg.setup" is considered unsafe, and will not be downloaded.`
The export into html is now a plain export.

How can I have the file being exported to html using the setup file?